# Kubernetes Monitoring: Heapster, InfluxDB, Grafana stack does seem to pass through data properly?

Tags: kubernetes

I was following the kubernetes/heapster doc for InfluxDB as storage backend and Grafana as frontend. Even though I can make the stack run, in terms of starting the services and pods, data won't be displayed in the fronted. The troubleshooting guide (namely exposing ports), didn't lead anywhere.

I have tried with different versions of heapster starting with 0.19.0 and also tried the addon in the k8s repo itself. The latter would start at all.

I am running on coreos and azure with weave.

Comment: In Grafana's data sources can you establish a connection to the pre-configured InfluxDB? Do the Heapster logs mention anything about failing to connect to InfluxDB?